# asm change cmd background color

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, bios, tasm

I wrote the part that changes the text color, but I can't find a way to change the background color, this code is for tasm assembly:

```
model small
stack 256
.data
ent db 0ah,0dh,'$'
array  db 2,4,5,6
       db 7,8,9,5
       db 1,2,3,4
       db 5,6,7,8
temp dw 0
.code
main :
    mov  ax,@data
    mov  ds,ax

    mov ah, 06h
    mov al, 0
    mov cx, 0
    mov dh, 79
    mov dl, 79
    mov bh, 4h

    int 10h
```

This is a my code but it doesn't work:

```
  mov ah, 0bh
    mov bh, 01h
    mov bl, 2h

    int 10h

    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 34h

    int 21h


 mov ax,4c00h ; exit from program
 int 21h

end main
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In BIOS function 6, BH contains an 8-bit color. Its lower 4 bits specify the foreground color while the upper 4 bits specify the background color. Try, for example, `mov bh, 14h` instead of `mov bh, 4h`. It should start writing red on blue instead of red on black.