# Changing screen Color in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

I am new to assembly language i want a way to change screen color in MASM (Console Color) i had searched in internet but i didn't find anything . I already had made the code that changes the text color 
this is the function that changes the text color

```
ChangeTextColor PROC
call crlf
mov edx,offset colormsg
call writestring
call crlf 
call readint
call clrscr
call setTextColor
ret
ChangeTextColorColor ENDP
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553330/asm-change-cmd-background-color

Comment: +1 for the feeling of putting me back to the mid 80s :-)

Comment: @Snoopy hhhhhhhhhhhh lol :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using system function as in c++ with the same commands example: "cls" to clear screen,  "color F5" to change cmd color to white and so on. In order to use system function you need to download
masm32 package if you don't have it from here http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm

this is the piece of code which do this job :

```
.model flat,stdcall
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
include  \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
system PROTO C, :PTR BYTE
.data

command BYTE "color A1",0
.code
main PROC

invoke system, ADDR command
exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links:

- [How to Change Screen Color Mode](http://www.carrsoft.com/pb/help/howtochangescreencolormode.html)
- [Writing with colours in asm](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=339)
- [Change cmd background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553330/asm-change-cmd-background-color)

Read and try. Read again and try again.

Hope that I helped you.

Comment: the first link illustrates how to change the console color from settings but i wabt the that makes this job in MASM

Comment: i made a search in Assembly language for x86 processors's book but i didn't find anything either

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with those proc names, sounds like all that Irvine stuff.

This type of thing would traditionally have been done with int 10h, however I assume you are talking about the text output on a Windows console, which makes this a question about the Windows API.

You need to look at:

[GetStdHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WriteConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)