# I need to change the color of console background and the color of the text also in assembly language

Tags: assembly, io, console, x86, masm

The code here is for Hello World simple program in assembly

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg db 0AH,0DH,"Hello World","$"
.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset msg
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
```

I want the code to change the color of console background and text color also.
I am using Dosbox to run this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553330/asm-change-cmd-background-color

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462807/printing-a-string-without-os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that it is solved by

```
 mov bl,9; this is for color
 mov cx, 11; this is for number of characters
 int 10h; puts the color behing
```

Just up on the 
mov dx, offset msg
Also add

```
 mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h
```

The working snippet

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    msg db "Hello World!","$"
.code

main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,09h
    mov bl,9; this is for color
    mov cx, 11; this is for number of characters
    int 10h; puts the color behing

    mov dx,offset hello_message
    int 21h

    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h

main endp
end main
```